# How to split dataframe column of list type into multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column named col which contains integer list type data. I want to split the list into col_1, col_2, col_3.
I tried the following things:

- Create 3 columns in the new dataframe.
- Then store the value of the col column of the first dataframe column into these three columns.
- Then, append the two dataframes. But I am not able to append the columns row-wise.

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.col.tolist(), columns=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'])  
df1 = df1.append(df2, sort = False)
```

Data is something like this:
col
[1,2,3]
[8,9]
Please let me know any approach which can split the columns row-wise.

[EDITED]

The issue that I am facing is the list doesn't have a uniform size. The size ranges from 0 to 3. A direct splitting as mentioned in other questions doesn't work.

Comment: is the list size in each row not uniform?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @FaizKidwai yes the size is not uniform. The size varies between  0 to 3.

Comment: For your case, since there is no uniformity in list size, first you'd need to transform it to have same length as the number of columns. Yo can do that using the `apply` function.
Once that is out of the way, you can simply convert it to list using `tolist()` function and set the value in new columns